# Cruisecontrol, deployment, folder permissions

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

We're using [cruisecontrol.net](http://cruisecontrol.net), it builds the version, creates a zip file, then 15 min later, unzips the file on the Integration server. But when the folder gets to the integration server, often, the security permission on one of the folders is totally hosed. The Domain admin and folder owner can't even open the folder in explorer. We reboot and the folder permissions are good we can delete the folder and redeploy the zip file and it's okay.

Does anyone have any idea what or how the folder permissions are getting so messed up?
Any tools to use to diagnose/watch what exactly is messing it up?

Comment: I have had this happen once by CruiseControl, except the folder was was a website root on a test server.  It couldn't be viewed or deleted (via remote desktop, at the machine, on the network). We had to reboot it and the folder magically disappeared. Never did find the problem, and (touch wood) it hasn't happened since.

Comment: Is it possible that it's marked for deletion and it can't delete so it's been put in that magic place where the OS deletes it on a reboot?

Does that seem to fit to anyone else?

I have nto had a chance to test this theory, but I wanted to see if anyone knew how to look at the file/folder and see if it's in this state.

Thanks,

E-

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using psexec from system internals to upzip to file on the remote machine rather than the build machine?

Also, it seems to me that rather than unzipping the zip just copy the stuff directly to the remote server. I'm not seeing the reason to zip it and then just unzip it?